# Braintree hosted field for added CC

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, braintree

I have set up braintree payment with hosted fields as follow:

In JS file:

```
braintree.setup(client_token, "custom", {
      id: "my-sample-form",
      paypal: {
          container: "paypal-container"
        },
        hostedFields: {
          number: {
            selector: '#my-credit-card-field',
          },
          cvv: {
            selector: '#my-security-code-field',
          },
          expirationDate: {
            selector: '#my-expiration-field',
          },
          postalCode: {
            selector: '#my-postal-code-field',
          }
        },
      });
```

I have no problems when trying to setup new customer, when they need to fill their CC details, however, when I try to setup existing customer, the JS file failed due to non existing `#my-credit-card-field`, etc..

In my new.html.erb, I have something like this:

```
 <% unless current_user.has_payment_info? %>
     <div id="my-credit-card" readonly>**** **** **** <%= @last_4_number %></div>
 <% else %>
     <div id="my-credit-card-field"></div>
     <div id="my-security-code-field"></div>
     <div id="my-expiration-field"></div>
     <div id="my-postal-code-field"></div>
 <% end %>
```

So I will ask cc details for new customer, and existing customers can save their payment method info. I have something like this in my controller:

```
def create
  @amount = params[:slider]
  @token = Braintree::Customer.find(current_user.braintree_customer_id).credit_cards.first.token
  unless current_user.has_payment_info?    
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
            amount: @amount,
            payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce],
            options: {
               store_in_vault: true
                     })
  else
    @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
            customer_id: current_user.braintree_customer_id,
            amount: @amount,
            payment_method_token: @token)
  end

if @result.success?
 #Some codes here
end
end
```

My problem:

If I set my id to `my-credit-card-field` for existing customer form, then they will need to fill the details due to hostedfields selector js. If I do not set any selectors, then there are errors in the JS file. So is there a better way to create the form for existing customers who has already set their payment method?

Thanks and any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do one of two things.

**Option 1: a simple hack.**

For the times when you do not need Braintree, add the divs to a place on your page outside your form like:

```
 <div style="display:none" id="my-credit-card-field"></div>
 <div style="display:none" id="my-security-code-field"></div>
 <div style="display:none" id="my-expiration-field"></div>
 <div style="display:none" id="my-postal-code-field"></div>
```

Now, on page load, Braintree will find them, and populate them, but nothing will get submitted.

Of course, when you DO need it, just don't add these hidden divs to the page (since they are already there in the form).

**Option 2 (recommended): Use partials.**

In the case where you don't need Braintree, then there's really no need to even call the javascript, right?  So, you can move your javascript into a partial that gets added to the page only when necessary.  This way, Braintree never even attempts to make the call to populate the divs in this case, so no errors.  Just include the render call in your conditional block.

While Option 1 is certainly faster, I would recommend Option 2 as it's probably the "right" approach, and you'll avoid the "why do we have his hidden div" question down the line when you forget about the hack.

Comment: Thanks, one last thing - How do I use partials for javascript?

Comment: Frankly there are many ways, but for something this straightforward, I would have a single partial view (yes, stored in app/views directory) that contains just the javascript. In that view, you can use the `javascript_tag` to do this (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-javascript_tag).  There are other methods, like using `content_for` in your views or using an alternate layout, but probably overkill (unless you specifically need the JS in the head tag (doubtful), then you'd want `content_for`).